# onbeforeunload method does not work if user does not interact with page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to call API before the user closes the browser tab So I have used `window.onbeforeunload` and it's working fine if user closes the tab within few seconds, but if user stays on page more than 2 minutes without doing anything on page, then `window.onbeforeunload` event is not triggered.

```
function winUnload() {
      id = window.sessionStorage.getItem('id');
      startDate = window.sessionStorage.getItem('startDate');
      endDate = Date.now();
    
      var data = {
        spend_time: endDate - startDate
      }
      if (id) {
          $http.put(URL, data).then(
            function success(data) {
            },
            function error() {
            }
        );
      }
      return 'Browser close button clicked';
    }
  
    window.onbeforeunload = winUnload;
```

Any suggestion on this would help, Thanks in advance!

Comment: From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event): ***However note that not all browsers support this method, and some instead require the event handler to implement one of two legacy methods:

assigning a string to the event's returnValue property or 
returning a string from the event handler.***

Comment: You'll also want to pass the `event` that you receive in the event handler over to `winUnload`, by making sure that call looks like: `winUnload(event)` so you can cancel the event (shown in the docs), otherwise you might as well just have `window.onbeforeunload = winUnload;`

Comment: @ScottMarcus Yes but if its not supported then it should not work at all. If user close tab within few seconds then its working but its not works if user stay more then 1 min without doing anything.

Comment: Before I would try to analyze why something isn't working the way I expect, I would make sure I'm using it the way I should. Also, I believe that the user having to interact with the document in some way is actually by design.

Comment: And, if you look at the docs at the compatibility chart at the bottom, you'll see that calling `event.preventDefault()` or setting the `returnValue` is needed in several clients.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Still not working, Yes might be its design to having interact with document then it should be not work if user close it within a few sec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of struggle, Finally found some resolution for this problem. Realised there is an issue with `$http` module before the http request gets complete the HTML resources get unlocked. After many trials, I come up with `navigator.sendBeacon()` method. For the latest browser, you could get it done like

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (event) {
    id = window.sessionStorage.getItem('id');
    startDate = window.sessionStorage.getItem('startDate');
    endDate = Date.now();

    data = new FormData();
    //For CSRF Token
    token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
    data.append("spend_time", endDate - startDate);
    data.append("authenticity_token", token);
  
    if (id) { 
      navigator.sendBeacon(URL, data);
      window.sessionStorage.setItem('startDate', Date.now());
    }
    
    // Cancel the event as stated by the standard.
    event.preventDefault();
    // Chrome requires returnValue to be set.
    event.returnValue = 'Are you sure you want to leave this page without saving?';
  });
```

For more details checkout [Navigator.sendBeacon()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon) and [Window: beforeunload event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event)